# Why can I find OUs using 'new DirectoryEntry(guid)' but not Principle.FindByIdentity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, active-directory

I am trying to locate the user accounts for our store locations using `DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` in .NET Core 2.1.

If I just new up a `DirectoryEntry` using the OU's guid it pulls the entry back no problem. But as soon as I try using the `AccountManagement` principal, it always returns null for the store's user account.

Each store location also has a distribution group as well, and I am able to locate those using `Principal.FindByIdentity`, just not the actual user account for the store.

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, _domainName, _username, _password)) 
{
    // returns null
    var testOU = Principal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.Guid, store.ActiveDirectoryOU.ToString());

    // returns proper DirectoryEntry for store's User Account
    var testEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<GUID=" + store.ActiveDirectoryOU + ">");

    // returns proper Principal for store's distribution group
    var testGroup = Principal.FindByIdentity(pc, store.ActiveDirectoryGroup.ToString());
}
```

Is there some sort of setting that prevents certain user accounts from being visible to `DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`? Or am I making some newb mistake?

Comment: I think (could be wrong) that there is nothing built into the Principal class to search on GUID of the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Principal.FindByIdentity rather than UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity to get the specific users. Is it possible that this could be the issue?

See [this example](https://tech.trailmax.info/2016/03/using-owin-and-active-directory-to-authenticate-users-in-asp-net-mvc-5-application/).

[See also >](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/PrincipalContext/-/php-principalcontext-class-examples.html)